# Firefox showing Blank page while running tests via selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**Find the below console error.**

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"HNu4L8KMZCeB","location":"app-global","version":"48.0","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1469558821000,"updateDate":1469558821000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":21899,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"48.0","maxVersion":"48.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true}
1474914296479   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1474914296480   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1474914296480   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1474914296480   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1474914296481   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1474914296483   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1474914296483   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1474914296483   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1474914296484   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.4
1474914296485   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1474914296486   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.4.3
1474914296506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1474914296507   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1474914296507   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1474914296507   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1474914296507   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1474914296507   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1474914296513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1474914296514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1474914296514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1474914296514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1474914296514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1474914296515   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1474914299023   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1474914299023   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1474914299024   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1474914299026   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1474914299380   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1474914299380   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1474914299384   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1474914299401   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1474914299401   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1474914299401   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1474914299405   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1474914299405   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1474914299477   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1474914299569   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at com.selenium.Test.main(Test.java:14)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"HNu4L8KMZCeB","location":"app-global","version":"48.0","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1469558821000,"updateDate":1469558821000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":21899,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"48.0","maxVersion":"48.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true}
1474914296479   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1474914296480   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1474914296480   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1474914296480   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1474914296481   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1474914296483   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1474914296483   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1474914296483   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1474914296484   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.4
1474914296485   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1474914296486   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.4.3
1474914296506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1474914296507   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1474914296507   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1474914296507   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1474914296507   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1474914296507   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1474914296513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1474914296514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1474914296514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1474914296514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1474914296514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1474914296515   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1474914299023   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1474914299023   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1474914299024   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1474914299026   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1474914299380   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1474914299380   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1474914299384   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1474914299401   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1474914299401   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1474914299401   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1474914299405   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1474914299405   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1474914299477   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1474914299569   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

Build info: version: '2.50.0', revision: '1070ace', time: '2016-01-27 18:40:08'
System info: host: 'admin-PC', ip: '192.168.100.2', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at com.selenium.Test.main(Test.java:14)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"HNu4L8KMZCeB","location":"app-global","version":"48.0","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1469558821000,"updateDate":1469558821000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":21899,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"48.0","maxVersion":"48.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true}
1474914296479   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1474914296480   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1474914296480   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1474914296480   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1474914296481   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1474914296483   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1474914296483   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1474914296483   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1474914296484   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.4
1474914296485   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1474914296486   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.4.3
1474914296506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1474914296507   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1474914296507   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1474914296507   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1474914296507   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1474914296507   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1474914296513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1474914296514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1474914296514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1474914296514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1474914296514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1474914296515   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1474914299023   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1474914299023   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1474914299024   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1474914299026   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1474914299380   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1474914299380   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1474914299384   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1474914299401   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1474914299401   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1474914299401   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1474914299405   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1474914299405   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1474914299477   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1474914299569   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7810

Comment: Satyam - I guess the version you are using I mis-matching. Might not supporting each other and it leads to an error "Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms."

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to post your Code which you use to initialize `firefox` web browser and the place where you exactly open the blank web browser.
Or 
Try to initialize `firefox` web driver with some custom wait time as below;

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver("./", new FirefoxOptions(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade you Firefox version from 48 to 46.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include Why the downgrade will fix the problem.  Is there a known issue/bug in 48 you can provide a link to?

Answer (score 0):

Try for creating Desired Capabilities for the firefox browser.

```
WebDriver driver;
String baseUrl , nodeUrl;
baseUrl = "https://www.google.com";
nodeUrl = "http://192.168.10.21:5568/wd/hub";

DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
capability.setPlatform(Platform.WIN8_1);

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl),capability);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```